# HttpContext.Session contains keys in one environment but not the other

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, session-variables

I have a .NET Core 2.1 MVC project that I upgraded to .NET Core 3.0 in steps according to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/proper-to-2x/?view=aspnetcore-3.0). The project uses `IHttpContextAccessor` to store several values in the `HttpContext.Session` collection and when I start the project with F5 on my development environment everything seems to be working. But when I publish the project to my test server the session key collection is empty and the values are no longer there.

Because the code should be the same on both environments I guess it must be related to how sessions are configured for the project, but I haven't been able to figure out a solution. This is how my `Startup.cs` is configured:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
    services.AddSession();
    ...
}
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    app.UseSession();
    ...
}
```

I tried serializing the Session object with Newtonsoft but the result was very limited:

```
{"IsAvailable":true,"Id":"44b1d511-e0cb-a1a3-c117-84033b80df25","Keys":[]}
```

Unfortunately the project cannot run by itself but is dependent on external input so it takes a considerable amount of time to test each scenario. Before I completely strip the project down I wanted to know if anyone might have a suggestion on what I could do to identify the cause for this.

Comment: Is there any reason you're registering `IHttpContextAccessor` manually? Why not use the built-in `services.AddHttpContextAccessor()`?

Comment: Where is [session state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1#configure-session-state) saved? Have you also checked session state cookie on requests?

Comment: Hi @GeoffJames not really, I'll try and see if it makes any difference

Comment: Hi @weichch my bad, I forgot to include the call to services.AddDistributedMemoryCache. I have added it in the example above

Comment: How often does your app pool gets recycled?

Comment: Can you clarify "The project uses IHttpContextAccessor to store several values" by posting an example because you wrote that sentence which sounds like HttpContext.Items but the rest of the post seems to be suggesting the issue is session not HttpContext.Items

Comment: @weichch I checked the settings for the app pool and it gets recycled once every 24 hours

Comment: Hi @AlanMacdonald I updated the description so that my intent is a bit more clear, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @StigPerez this post is still confusing.  Weichch asked "Where is session state saved?" to which you replied that you forgot to add the call to services.AddDistributedMemoryCache. Distributed cache does not equal session. Where is your session stored?  In proc?  On a session state server?  On the test servers is it a web farm or a single server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what the issue was and it was a bit of a blunder. It seems I forgot to configure the cookie settings when adding session as a service in `Startup.cs`. So instead of this:

```
services.AddSession();
```

it should have been this:

```
services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.None;
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
});
```

Why I got it to work on my local environment is still not answered. Maybe it had something to do with the fact that I was accessing the MVC project from a test-page on localhost (the same domain for the MVC project) but on my test server the MVC project is on a different domain. Still, everything now works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem today. So I updated by web.config which is generated from published project to add following code.

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.webServer>
    ...
    <modules>
      <remove name="Session" />
      <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>
      ...
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Note: I am running app in self-contained mode and ApplicationPool is set to no managed code and finally I use urlrewrite to reverse proxy to localhost:5000 to run .net core app on iis

Comment: Unfortunately, adding the session settings in web.config did not resolve the issue

Comment: No you need you need to run app exe separate point iis to empty directory in self contained mode then it will store session

Comment: You will need to run app as a reverse proxy to localhost:5000 using url rewrite

Comment: And you also need to install asp.net core hosting bundle